# JSON parsing android

Tags: java, android, json, networkonmainthread

I need advice about my code.

I'm trying to parse a JSON array generated by the PHP function `json_encode()`.

**My json:**

`{"data": [{"streamer":"froggen","yt_length":"25078"},{"streamer":"wingsofdeath","yt_length":"8979"},{"streamer":"guardsmanbob","yt_length":"4790"},{"streamer":"kaostv","yt_length":"4626"},{"streamer":"kungentv","yt_length":"3883"},{"streamer":"destiny","yt_length":"3715"},{"streamer":"zekent","yt_length":"3428"},{"streamer":"athenelive","yt_length":"1673"},{"streamer":"frommaplestreet","yt_length":"1614"},{"streamer":"keyorikeys","yt_length":"1410"},{"streamer":"riotgamesturkish","yt_length":"1397"},{"streamer":"vman7","yt_length":"1022"},{"streamer":"tiensinoakuma","yt_length":"967"},{"streamer":"affenklappe","yt_length":"748"},{"streamer":"teamkeyd","yt_length":"747"},{"streamer":"lagtvmaximusblack","yt_length":"683"},{"streamer":"lolgameru","yt_length":"665"},{"streamer":"gruntartv","yt_length":"585"},{"streamer":"entenzwerg","yt_length":"579"},{"streamer":"lolgameru_cauthonpro","yt_length":"506"},{"streamer":"basickz","yt_length":"488"},{"streamer":"ilysuiteheart","yt_length":"491"},{"streamer":"kireiautumn","yt_length":"485"},{"streamer":"ultimavv","yt_length":"471"}]}`

**Java class:**

```
public class JSONParser {
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";
String response = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {
}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
}
}
```

**And my activity:**

```
public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends ListActivity {
// url to make request
private static String url = "http://ololo.tv/vasa";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_DATA = "data";
private static final String TAG_STREAMER = "streamer";
private static final String TAG_VIEWERS = "yt_length";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray data = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser Parser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = null;

        json = Parser.getJSONFromUrl(url);


    try {
        // Getting Array of Contacts
        data = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);

        // looping through All Contacts
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String streamer = c.getString(TAG_STREAMER);
            String viewers = c.getString(TAG_VIEWERS);
            //String link = c.getString();

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_STREAMER, streamer);
            map.put(TAG_VIEWERS, viewers);
            //map.put(TAG_URL, link);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            dataList.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, dataList,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { TAG_STREAMER, TAG_VIEWERS /*TAG_URL*/ }, new int[] {
                    R.id.streamer, R.id.viewers /*R.id.url*/ });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.streamer)).getText().toString();
            String viewers_count = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.viewers)).getText().toString();
            //String url = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.url)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_STREAMER, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_VIEWERS, viewers_count);
            //in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, url);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
}
}
```

I tried using breakpoints, and see that when I put a breakpoint after `GetEntity`, the program doesn't get there because it crashed early, or something.

This my async task.

```
public class  ParsingTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{


JSONParser Parser = new JSONParser();

protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    JSONObject json = Parser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
        // Getting Array of Contacts
        data = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);

        // looping through All Contacts
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String streamer = c.getString(TAG_STREAMER);
            String viewers = c.getString(TAG_VIEWERS);
            //String link = c.getString();

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_STREAMER, streamer);
            map.put(TAG_VIEWERS, viewers);
            //map.put(TAG_URL, link);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            dataList.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, dataList,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { TAG_STREAMER, TAG_VIEWERS /*TAG_URL*/ }, new int[] {
            R.id.streamer, R.id.viewers /*R.id.url*/ });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    return null;
}
protected void onProgressUpdate() {

}
protected void onPostExecute() {

}

}
```

ListAdapter error, seems like something wrong in "this". This my version how cut off code, where it stop return variables. Sorry for bad english, but i hope you understand me :)

Add my php json maker. Mb problem there?!

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 if (!mysql_select_db("ololo")) {
    echo "Unable to select ololo: " . mysql_error();
    }
$sql=mysql_query("select streamer, yt_length from pm_videos where category='1'");
if(!$sql) exit("Error - ".mysql_error().", ".$tmp_q);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
$output[]=$row;
}
$json = json_encode($output);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
print "{\"data\": ${json}}";
mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You programm crashes because you are running

```
json = Parser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

in the UI Thread context. You have to use an [AsyncTask](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2009/05/painless-threading.html)

Code looks good. The only problem is that

```
 public class  ParsingTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>{


 JSONParser Parser = new JSONParser();

 protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
JSONObject json = Parser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

try {
    // Getting Array of Contacts
    data = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);

    // looping through All Contacts
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
        JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

        // Storing each json item in variable
        String streamer = c.getString(TAG_STREAMER);
        String viewers = c.getString(TAG_VIEWERS);
        //String link = c.getString();

        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(TAG_STREAMER, streamer);
        map.put(TAG_VIEWERS, viewers);
        //map.put(TAG_URL, link);

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        dataList.add(map);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

/**
 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
 * */


return dataList;
  }

 protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataList) {
  ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AndroidJSONParsingActivity.this, dataList,
        R.layout.list_item,
        new String[] { TAG_STREAMER, TAG_VIEWERS /*TAG_URL*/ }, new int[] {
        R.id.streamer, R.id.viewers /*R.id.url*/ });

setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: oh... seems like that is it. I need to modify my JSONParser class extends AsyncTask? But i really not stand about three metod in it. 1. DoInBackground. 2.OnProgressUpdate 3.OnPostExecute. I need to paste code of my getJSONFromURL() method there? Thank you.

Comment: You need to run json = Parser.getJSONFromUrl(url) and the parsing code inside doInBackground.

Comment: sorry for my cheek... but last 3 hours i tried use async threading, but cant' stand how i can return values after their work. Can you explain me? Bcs in all docs examples doing "stand-alone" actions or maybe I understand there is something wrong. Thank you.

Comment: posted up. Thant you a lot)     ^

Comment: my code is right?? I have error in ListAdapter. In context = this. java: constructor SimpleAdapter in class android.widget.SimpleAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
  required: android.content.Context,java.util.List<? extends java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?>>,int,java.lang.String[],int[]
  found: com.androidhive.jsonparsing.AndroidJSONParsingActivity.ParsingTask,java.util.ArrayList<java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>>[],int,java.lang.String[],int[]
  reason: actual argument

Comment: I modified your Asynctask. The third paramter is what doInBackground returns and what onPostExecute receive as paramter. onPostExecute is executed on the UI Thread so you are good modifyng the UI

Comment: This code works!! Thank you very much:) but still crashing. My breakpoints indicate crash in line `HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();`. Previous line - works.. Ohh.. My head(( why, God. ((

Comment: do you have the internet permission inside your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: yes. ` <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` crashes can be if no have entity in url?? how can i check this?

Comment: What kind of exception did you get?

Comment: yes. ` <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` hm.. its not entity.. there are i havn't response.. but WHY. (((

Comment: Probably the issue is server side but I am not experienced. Feel free to.ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) ([docs](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide))?

```
public static final class Content {
    @SerializedName("streamer")  // you don't need to specify this, JFYI
    String streamer;

    @SerializedName("yt_length") // you don't need to specify this, JFYI
    String yt_length;
}

public static final class Data {
    @SerializedName("data") 
    List<Content> data;
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    Data data = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Data.class);
}
```

And remember, you cannot call network operations on UI thread! this is reason of what you have for now.

Comment: it seems like problem not in parse part. I cant get my json string from url. maybe charset is trouble?!

Answer (score 0):

**json data**

```
 [
 -{
 Cat_Id: 21
 Cat_Title: "Electronics"
 Cat_Description: null
 Cat_Status: 0
 Cat_CreatedBy: 0
 Cat_CreatedDate: "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
 Cat_UpdatedBy: 0
 Cat_UpdatedDate: "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
 }
```

**Category class**

```
 public class Category {

 public int Cat_Id;
 public String Cat_Title = null;;

 public Category() {

 }

 public int getCat_Id() {
 return Cat_Id;
 }

 public void setCat_Id(int Cat_Id) {
 this.Cat_Id = Cat_Id;
 }

 }
```

**BaseActivity**

```
 public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

 public ProgressDialog progressDialog;
 public SharedPreferences prefs;
 public JSONObject jsonObject;
 public JSONObject jsonObject1;
 public static String pref_setting = "Category_setting";

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
 progressDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
 prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
 Preferences.AppContext = this;
 }

 protected void onStop() {
 super.onStop();
 if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
 progressDialog.dismiss();
 }
 }

 }
```

**Soap**

public class Soap {

```
 // public static String BaseURL = "";
 public static String BaseURL = "";
 public static String imgURL = "";

 public static String getSoapResponseByGet(String postFixOfUrl)
 throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
 if (Preferences.AppContext != null
 && Preferences.isOnline(Preferences.AppContext)) {

 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(BaseURL + postFixOfUrl);
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

 String xmlString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
 return xmlString.toString();

 } else {
 return "{\"error\":{\"no_internet\":\"No internet connection\"}}";
 }
 }

 public static String getSoapResponse(String postFixOfUrl)
 throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
 if (Preferences.AppContext != null
 && Preferences.isOnline(Preferences.AppContext)) {
 HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(BaseURL + postFixOfUrl);

 StringEntity se = new StringEntity("", HTTP.UTF_8);
 se.setContentType("text/xml");
 httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8");
 httpPost.setEntity(se);

 HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

 BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse) httpClient
 .execute(httpPost);

 HttpEntity r_Entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
 String xmlString = EntityUtils.toString(r_Entity);
 return xmlString.toString();
 } else {
 return "{\"error\":{\"no_internet\":\"No internet connection\"}}";
 }
 }

 public static String getSoapResponseByPost(String postFixOfUrl,
 ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs)
 throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
 if (Preferences.AppContext != null
 && Preferences.isOnline(Preferences.AppContext)) {

 HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(BaseURL + postFixOfUrl);

 httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));

 HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse) httpClient
 .execute(httpPost);

 HttpEntity r_Entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

 String xmlString = EntityUtils.toString(r_Entity);

 return xmlString.toString();
 } else {
 return "{\"error\":{\"no_internet\":\"No internet connection\"}}";
 }
 }



 // ////////// api for Category //////////////

 http://sharafdg.digitarabia.com/sharafdg/api/Category

 public static String apiGetCategory() throws ClientProtocolException,
 IOException {

 String result = Soap.getSoapResponseByGet("api/Category");
 Log.e("SOAP", result);
 return result;
 }


 public static String apiGetstore(int catid, int brandid, int modelid,
 String variant) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

 String result = Soap.getSoapResponseByGet("api/stores/?catid=" + catid
 + "&brandid=" + brandid + "&modelid=" + modelid + "&variant="
 + variant);

 Log.e("SOAPSTORE", "api/stores/?catid=" + catid);
 Log.e("SOAPSTORE", "api/stores/?&brandid=" + brandid);
 Log.e("SOAPSTORE", "api/stores/?&modelid=" + modelid);
 Log.e("SOAPSTORE", "api/stores/?&variant=" + variant);
 return result;

 }


 -------------- post method hoy to -----------------


 http://kallapp.madword-media.co.uk/company.php?category_id=11
 http://kallapp.madword-media.co.uk/categories.php



 public static String apiGetCategory() throws ClientProtocolException,
 IOException {
 ArrayList<NameValuePair> alNameValuePairs = new
 ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

 String result = Soap.getSoapResponseByPost("categories.php",
 alNameValuePairs);

 return result;
 }

 public static String apiGetcompanies(String category_id)
 throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

 ArrayList<NameValuePair> alNameValuePairs = new
 ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

 // NameValuePair nameValuePairs = new BasicNameValuePair("",
 // category_id);
 // alNameValuePairs.add(nameValuePairs);

 String result = Soap.getSoapResponse("company.php?category_id="
 + category_id);
 Log.e("SOAP", result);
 return result;

 }

 public static String apiGetDepaName(String category_id, String
 company_id)
 throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

 ArrayList<NameValuePair> alNameValuePairs = new
 ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

 NameValuePair nameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("category_id",
 category_id);
 alNameValuePairs.add(nameValuePair);

 nameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("company_id", company_id);
 alNameValuePairs.add(nameValuePair);

 String result =
 Soap.getSoapResponseByPost("department.php?",alNameValuePairs);

 return result;

 }
```

**Category_list**

```
 public class Category_list extends BaseActivity {

 int currentCategoryid;

 private ArrayList<Category> cat = new ArrayList<Category>();
 ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
 Spinner spinner;
 Button btncompare;
 private int catid;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 setContentView(R.layout.activity_webservices);
 spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
 btncompare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncompare);

 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelected());

 new getCategoryTask().execute();

 btncompare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Store.class);
 intent.putExtra("catid", catid);
 startActivity(intent);

 }
 });

 }

 public class OnItemSelected implements OnItemSelectedListener {

 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
 long arg3) {
 // ((TextView) arg0.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

 catid = cat.get(arg2).Cat_Id;
 String cateid = String.valueOf(catid);
 Log.e("cateid_category", cateid);
 // new getBrandTask().execute();

 }

 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
 }
 }

 private class getCategoryTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

 Category category;
 String categoryJsonStr;

 public getCategoryTask() {

 category = new Category();

 }

 protected void onPreExecute() {
 super.onPreExecute();
 // progressDialog.show();

 }

 @Override
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 -----------------------admin email-pass-------------

 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(userJsonStr);//
 jsonUserArray.getJSONObject(i);
 currentUserid = jsonObject.getInt("Use_Id");
 if (currentUserid > 0) {

 if (!jsonObject.isNull("Use_Id")) {
 id = jsonObject.getInt("Use_Id");
 }

 }




 --------------------kallapp---------
 try {

 Log.i("categoryJsonStr", categoryJsonStr);
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(categoryJsonStr);
 JSONArray jsonCatArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("categories");

 for (int i = 0; i < jsonCatArray.length(); i++) {

 Category objcategory = new Category();
 jsonObject = jsonCatArray.getJSONObject(i);

 --------------------------------------------------------------


 try {

 // categoryJsonStr = Soap.apiGetCategory();

 Log.e("categoryJsonStr", categoryJsonStr);

 JSONArray jsonCatArray = new JSONArray(categoryJsonStr);

 Category category = new Category();
 // category.Cat_Id = -1;
 category.Cat_Title = "Select Category";
 cat.add(category);
 list.add(category.Cat_Title);

 for (int i = 0; i < jsonCatArray.length(); i++) {

 Category objcategory = new Category();
 JSONObject jsonObject = jsonCatArray.getJSONObject(i);

 currentCategoryid = jsonObject.getInt("Cat_Id");

 if (!jsonObject.isNull("Cat_Title")) {
 objcategory.setCat_Title(jsonObject
 .getString("Cat_Title"));
 }

 if (!jsonObject.isNull("Cat_Id")) {
 objcategory.setCat_Id(jsonObject.getInt("Cat_Id"));
 }

 cat.add(objcategory);
 list.add(objcategory.Cat_Title);

 }

 } catch (Exception e) {
 // TODO: handle exception
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
 return null;

 }

 public void onPostExecute(Void result) {

 super.onPostExecute(result);
 // progressDialog.dismiss();

 spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Category_list.this,
 android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list));
 spinner.setSelection(0, true);

 }

 }

 }
 -------------more than one item fill--------
 store_lists.add(objStore_list);

 public void onPostExecute(Void result) {

 super.onPostExecute(result);
 store_adapter = new Store_adapter(Store.this, store_lists);
 lv_store.setAdapter(store_adapter);
 store_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

 }
```

**Preferences**

```
 public class Preferences {

 public static Context AppContext = null;
 public static String categoryid;


 public static boolean isOnline(Context c) {
 ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) c
 .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

 return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
 && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();

 }
 }
```

**Store_adapter**

```
 private Context mContext;
 private int ImageCount;
 private ArrayList<Store_list> store_lists = new ArrayList<Store_list>();
 public ImageLoader imageLoader;
 ImageView imgsave, imgpackage, img_up_arrow, img_dun_arrow;
 TextView txtsave;
 RelativeLayout relatv;

 public Store_adapter(Context c, ArrayList<Store_list> store_lists) {

 mContext = c;

 this.store_lists = store_lists;
 this.ImageCount = store_lists.size();
 imageLoader = new ImageLoader(c);
 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 // ImageCount = store_lists.size();
 return this.ImageCount;
 }

 @Override
 public Object getItem(int arg0) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return null;
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return 0;
 }

 public void notifyDataSetChanged() {

 super.notifyDataSetChanged();
 this.ImageCount = store_lists.size();
 }

 public void remove(int position) {
 store_lists.remove(position);
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
 .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.storelist, parent, false);

 TextView name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtprise);
 ImageView imgview = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgve);

 Store_list list = store_lists.get(position);

 imageLoader.DisplayImage(list.Store_logo, imgview);
 name.setText(String.valueOf(list.Mod_Price));
 return vi;

 }
 }
```

**menifestfile**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
 />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
 />
```

Comment: Could you specify a bit more about your answer? Dumping a lot of code isn't usually going to help a lot of people unless you specify what it does etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getSoapResponse(String postFixOfUrl) {
        try {
            if (General.AppContext != null
                    && General.isOnline(General.AppContext)) {

                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(BaseURL + postFixOfUrl);
                Log.i("SOAP", "URI:" + BaseURL + postFixOfUrl);

                httpget.setHeader("Content-Type",
                        "application/json;charset=utf-8");

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse) httpclient
                        .execute(httpget);
                HttpEntity r_entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                String xmlString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);

                return xmlString.toString();
            } else {
                // return
                // "[{\"erorr\":{\"no_internet\":\"No internet connection\"}}]";
                if (General.AppActivity != null) {
                    General.AppActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    General.AppContext,
                                    General.AppContext
                                            .getResources()
                                            .getString(
                                                    R.string.no_internet_connection),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            HandleException.catchException(e, true);
        }
        return null;
    }



// post method
    public static String getSoapResponseByPost(String postFixOfUrl,
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs)
            throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        try {
            if (General.AppContext != null
                    && General.isOnline(General.AppContext)) {

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(BaseURL + postFixOfUrl);
                Log.i("SOAP", "URI:" + BaseURL + postFixOfUrl);
                // httppost.setHeader("Content-Type",
                // "text/html;charset=utf-8");

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,
                        "UTF-8"));

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse) httpclient
                        .execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity r_entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                String xmlString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);

                return xmlString.toString();
            } else {
                // return
                // "[{\"erorr\":{\"no_internet\":\"No internet connection\"}}]";

                if (General.AppActivity != null) {
                    General.AppActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    General.AppContext,
                                    General.AppContext
                                            .getResources()
                                            .getString(
                                                    R.string.no_internet_connection),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            HandleException.catchException(e, true);
        }
        return null;
    }


public static String getSoapResponseForImage(String postFixOfUrl,
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs,
            List<NameValuePair> filenameValuePairs) {
        String xmlString = null;
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(BaseURL + postFixOfUrl);

        try {
            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

            for (int index = 0; index < filenameValuePairs.size(); index++) {
                File myFile = new File(filenameValuePairs.get(index).getValue());
                if (myFile.exists()) {
                    FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(myFile);

                    entity.addPart(filenameValuePairs.get(index).getName(),
                            fileBody);
                }

            }

            for (int index = 0; index < nameValuePairs.size(); index++) {

                entity.addPart(nameValuePairs.get(index).getName(),
                        new StringBody(nameValuePairs.get(index).getValue(),
                                Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            }

            httpPost.setEntity(entity);

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
            xmlString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("SOAP ", "Result : " + xmlString.toString());
        return xmlString.toString();
    }

public class ParsedResponse {
    public Object o;
    public boolean error = false;
}


public class General {

    public static Context AppContext = null;
    public static Activity AppActivity = null;
public static boolean isOnline(Context c) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) c
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }}

public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
protected SharedPreferences prefs;
    public ProgressDialog progressDialog;

General.AppContext = getApplicationContext();
        General.AppActivity = BaseActivity.this;

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);}


public class ErrorMgmt {
    private Boolean error;
    private String errorMessage;
    private String exceptionMessage;

    public ErrorMgmt(String exceptionMessage) {
        error = false;
        errorMessage = "";
        this.exceptionMessage = exceptionMessage;
    }

    public ErrorMgmt() {
        error = false;
        errorMessage = "";
        exceptionMessage = "";
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        if (error) {
            if (errorMessage.equals("")) {
                return exceptionMessage;
            } else {
                return errorMessage;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public Boolean strError(String JsonResponse) {
        this.error = false;
        errorMessage = "";
        try {
            JSONObject objJson = new JSONObject(JsonResponse);
            String strJson = objJson.getString("JsonResponse");

            if(!strJson.equals("Please enter valid email")) {
                this.error = true ;
                errorMessage = "";


            } else {
                this.error = false;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            this.error = true;
            errorMessage = "";
            HandleException.catchException(e, true);
        }
        return this.error;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public Boolean isObjError(String JsonResponse) {
        this.error = false;
        errorMessage = "";
        try {
            JSONObject objJson = new JSONObject(JsonResponse);
            if (objJson != null && !objJson.isNull("error") ) {
                this.error = true;
                Iterator IError = objJson.keys();
                errorMessage = "";
                while (IError.hasNext()) {
                    String key = (String) IError.next();
                    errorMessage += objJson.getString(key) + "\n";
                }
            } else if (objJson != null && !objJson.isNull("statusCode")) {
                Integer statusCode = objJson.getInt("statusCode");
                if (statusCode > 200) {
                    this.error = true;
                } else {
                    this.error = false;
                }
            } else {
                this.error = false;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            this.error = true;
            errorMessage = "";
            HandleException.catchException(e, true);
        }
        return this.error;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public Boolean isError(String JsonResponse) {
        this.error = false;
        errorMessage = "";
        try {
            JSONArray arrJson = new JSONArray(JsonResponse);
            if (!arrJson.isNull(0) && !arrJson.getJSONObject(0).isNull("erorr")) {
                this.error = true;

                JSONObject objError = arrJson.getJSONObject(0);
                Iterator IError = objError.keys();
                errorMessage = "";
                while (IError.hasNext()) {
                    String key = (String) IError.next();
                    errorMessage += objError.getString(key) + "\n";
                }
            } else if (!arrJson.isNull(0)
                    && !arrJson.getJSONObject(0).isNull("statusCode")) {
                Integer statusCode = arrJson.getJSONObject(0).getInt(
                        "statusCode");
                if (statusCode > 200) {
                    this.error = true;
                } else {
                    this.error = false;
                }
            } else {
                this.error = false;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            this.error = true;
            errorMessage = "";
            HandleException.catchException(e, true);
        }
        return this.error;
    }

    public void SetForsedError(Boolean val) {
        error = true;
    }
}

// Api for register with Email

    public static ParsedResponse apiRegister(String name, String email,
            String password) throws Exception {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> alNameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        NameValuePair nameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("name", name);
        alNameValuePairs.add(nameValuePair);

        nameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("email", email);
        alNameValuePairs.add(nameValuePair);

        nameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("password", password);
        alNameValuePairs.add(nameValuePair);

        // nameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("fb_uid", "");
        // alNameValuePairs.add(nameValuePair);

        String result = Soap.getSoapResponseByPost("user/register",
                alNameValuePairs);

        Log.e("apiRegister", result);

        ErrorMgmt errMgmt = new ErrorMgmt(General.AppContext.getResources()
                .getString(R.string.error_loading_data));
        ParsedResponse p = new ParsedResponse();

        p.error = false;

        if (result != null && !result.equals("")) {

            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
            String code = "";
            if (!jObject.isNull("statusCode")) {
                code = jObject.getString("statusCode");
            }

            if (code.equals("200")) {

                JSONArray jsonArray = jObject.getJSONArray("User");
                if (jsonArray.length() > 0) {

                    ArrayList<UserData> arrayList = new ArrayList<UserData>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        UserData objUserData = new UserData();

                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("uid")) {
                            objUserData.uid = jsonObject.getString("uid");
                        }

                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("name")) {
                            objUserData.name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                        }

                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("email")) {
                            objUserData.email = jsonObject.getString("email");
                        }

                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("password")) {
                            objUserData.password = jsonObject
                                    .getString("password");
                        }

                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("created_date")) {
                            objUserData.created_date = jsonObject
                                    .getString("created_date");
                        }

                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("status")) {
                            objUserData.status = jsonObject.getString("status");
                        }

                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("fb_uid")) {
                            objUserData.fb_uid = jsonObject.getString("fb_uid");
                        }

                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("account_type")) {
                            objUserData.account_type = jsonObject
                                    .getString("account_type");
                        }

                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("profile_img")) {
                            objUserData.profile_img = jsonObject
                                    .getString("profile_img");
                        }

                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("birthdate")) {
                            objUserData.birthdate = jsonObject
                                    .getString("birthdate");
                        }

                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("city")) {
                            objUserData.city = jsonObject.getString("city");
                        }

                        JSONArray jsonArray2 = jsonObject
                                .getJSONArray("usersubscribe");
                        if (jsonArray2.length() > 0) {

                            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < jsonArray2.length(); i1++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray2
                                        .getJSONObject(i1);
                                if (!jsonObject2.isNull("isSubscribe")) {
                                    objUserData.isSubscribe = jsonObject2
                                            .getString("isSubscribe");

                                }
                                if (!jsonObject2.isNull("amount")) {
                                    objUserData.amount = jsonObject2
                                            .getString("amount");
                                }

                            }

                        }

                        arrayList.add(objUserData);
                        p.o = arrayList;
                    }
                } else {
                    errMgmt = new ErrorMgmt(General.AppActivity.getResources()
                            .getString(R.string.err_norecords));
                    errMgmt.SetForsedError(true);
                    p.o = errMgmt;
                    p.error = true;
                }

            }

            if (code.equals("401")) {
                errMgmt = new ErrorMgmt(General.AppActivity.getResources()
                        .getString(R.string.allready_regi));
                errMgmt.SetForsedError(true);
                p.o = errMgmt;
                p.error = true;
            }

        } else {
            errMgmt = new ErrorMgmt(General.AppActivity.getResources()
                    .getString(R.string.err_norecords));
            errMgmt.SetForsedError(true);
            p.o = errMgmt;
            p.error = true;
        }

        return p;
    }


// Login with Facebook

    private class GetFacebookLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private ParsedResponse p = null;
        private String message = "";
        private Boolean error = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                p = new ParsedResponse();
                p = Soap.apiUserLoginFacebook(fbID);
                if (p.error) {
                    ErrorMgmt errmgmt = (ErrorMgmt) p.o;
                    message = errmgmt.getErrorMessage();
                    error = true;
                } else {
                    arrayList.clear();
                    arrayList.addAll((ArrayList<UserData>) p.o);
                    error = false;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                message = "problem in loading data";
                error = true;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (error) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(Register_Login_Screen.this)
                        .setMessage(message)
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                }).show();
            } else {
                UserData objUserData = new UserData();
                for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
                    objUserData = arrayList.get(i);
                }
                String profileImage = "";
                try {
                    URL image_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"
                            + fbID + "/picture?height=150&width=150");
                    profileImage = String.valueOf(image_value);
                    Log.e("fb_image_path", "" + image_value);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                Editor e = prefs.edit();
                e.putBoolean(General.PREFS_login, true);
                e.putString(General.PREFS_Uid, objUserData.uid);
                e.putString(General.PREFS_name, objUserData.name);
                e.putString(General.PREFS_email, objUserData.email);
                e.putString(General.PREFS_fb_uid, objUserData.fb_uid);
                e.putString(General.PREFS_logintype, General.PREFS_valuefblogin);
                if (objUserData.profile_img != null
                        && !objUserData.profile_img.equals("")) {
                    e.putString(General.PREFS_profile_img,
                            objUserData.profile_img);
                } else {
                    e.putString(General.PREFS_profile_img, profileImage);
                }
                e.putString(General.PREFS_account_type,
                        objUserData.account_type);
                e.putString(General.PREFS_birthdate, objUserData.birthdate);
                e.putString(General.PREFS_city, objUserData.city);
                e.putString(General.PREFS_subscribed, objUserData.isSubscribe);
                e.putString(General.PREFS_amount, objUserData.amount);
                String[] strings = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < objUserData.screenerArr.size(); i++) {
                    String queString = objUserData.screenerArr.get(i);
                    strings = queString.split(",");
                    String question1 = strings[0];
                    e.putString("RosaRosa_screener_question" + (i + 1),
                            question1);
                    e.putBoolean("RosaRosa_screener_ans" + (i + 1), true);

                    String ans1 = strings[1];
                    e.putString(
                            "RosaRosa_screener_question" + (i + 1) + "_ans",
                            ans1);

                    Log.e("question", "" + question1 + ans1);
                }

                e.commit();

                Toast.makeText(Register_Login_Screen.this, R.string.succ_login,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Register_Login_Screen.this,
                        Personal_Stylist_Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }

    }
```